# Importing via csv data in jsonb format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, mobility

Using the `mobility` gem for i18n, the process of importing data from CSV for `jsonb` data is not succeeding.

Whereas, one generally imports

```
Class.create(
  name_en: row[2],
  name_fr: row[3],
  [...]
```

for the local-driven values in a key_value backend,  with a [postgresql backend](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility/wiki/Postgres-Backends-%28Column-Attribute%29) the column has to be populated with hash, with the key and value.

However, the syntax is incorrect
`name: { 'en' = row[2], 'fr' =  row[2]}` leads to error
`syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '.' or &. or :: or '['`

and `name: { 'en': row[2], 'fr': row[2]}` seems syntaxtically correct, but yields
`Error importing row because 'No plugin configured for these keys: type.'`

*note* this occurs with any of the following definitions in config/initializers/mobility.rb`

```
    backend :jsonb
    backend :jsonb, type: :json
    backend :jsonb, type: :string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to set it up. It's actually straightforward, mobility's docs on github make it more confusing than it is.

Set up your migrations with `jsonb` columns for each attribute, it's recommended to set default as well `default: {}`.

```
# db/migrate/20220402201700_create_articles.rb
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.jsonb :title, default: {}
    end
  end
end
```

Model set up is unchanged
https://github.com/shioyama/mobility#getting-started

```
# app/models/article.rb
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  extend Mobility
  translates :title
end
```

To set up locale accessors, `locale_accessors` plugin must be enabled.
https://github.com/shioyama/mobility#-getting-and-setting-translations

```
# config/initializers/mobility.rb
Mobility.configure do
  plugins do
    backend :jsonb
    locale_accessors # enable locale accessors, like 'name_en'
    # ...
  end
end
```

Import transaltions

```rb
Article.create(title_en: 'Importing via csv data in jsonb format',
               title_fr: 'Importation via des données csv au format jsonb')

# Article.last.title_backend.read(:fr) # => "Importation via des ..."
```

```
# this doesn't work, as far as I can tell
# it'll wrap the entire hash in `en` locale
Article.create(title: { en: '', fr: ''} )
```

For other ways to save translations: https://github.com/shioyama/mobility#-getting-and-setting-translations

`mobility v1.2.6` `rails v7.0.2.3` `ruby v3.1.1`

Comment: I went down that path.  I have same versions and set up as you suggest save an added index on migration `t.jsonb :name, index: true, default: {}`  Hit `Error importing row because 'No plugin configured for these keys: type.'` so syntax correct, but something else at play> Even tried specifying in `backend :jsonb, type: :json` in config file. Odd.

Comment: the only way I got that error is doing this `translates :name, type: :string`; that option is only for `key_value` backend. https://github.com/shioyama/mobility/blob/v1.2.6/README.md?plain=1#L186

Comment: Oh, sweet!  lack of interpretation of the applicable backend + assimilation of the configuration threw me off kilter!